# How can I prevent a loop to create keys without quotes?

Tags: php, arrays, key, quotes

This is my loop:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
          $array1[$value->getUuid()][$value->getFields()->getName()] = $value->getContent();
        }
```

The result is:

```
array:2 [▼
  "d8ab80f4f6" => array:16 [▶]
  9087785727 => array:16 [▶]
]
```

I do not understand, why the last key does not have quotes. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Because __string__ keys which consist only of numbers are turned into __numeric__ keys: `"1"` becomes `1`, `"42"` becomes `42`, etc. This behaviour is described in a manual.

Comment: FYI - see the list of conversions in the section `Additionally the following key casts will occur:` in https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.array-func